# Limiting download speed using Java

Tags: java, download

I am new to java programming.I need help in making a program in which i can limit the Downloading speed of a person. I want to do this task like this:

I want to input I.p of a person whom Downloading speed i want to limit. Then I will enter downloading speed like 50 kbps/Mbps. After entering values I will click button which will limit the downloading speed of the person whom I.p I have entered.

I have searched on google but I haven't found any good tutorial to learn this .Anyone who can guide me in right direction . Any tutorial that can give me a start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: download speed is limited by ISP, if you want to change those manually by creating program using java it isnt very practical

Comment: We told you the last time you asked this question: you can't and especially **you** can't.

Comment: user3659052 can u guide me how i can limit the downloading speed of a person ?

Comment: @Kayaman It's absolutely possible; JDownloader does it just fine. But it's certainly not *simple*.

Comment: What if @saki is writing a download manager app? I would really want a download manager to be able to throttle my download/upload speed.

Comment: @chrylis He wants to enter the IP address and limit a person's download speed based on that. JDownloader certainly can't do that.

Comment: @sleblanc He can't even write a proper question on SO. I think you're giving him too much credit.

Comment: @kayaman that is why i mentioned that i am new to java programming . If u know the right question for this please help me

Comment: Please review guide on asking appropriate questions on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @saki You want to limit someone's downloading speed? Do you mean that you want to be able to put let's say my IP address and limit my download speed?

Comment: All OP wants is a booter. Is that really too much to ask? ;-)

Comment: for starter, ISP have your total speed per your current network. if you are using LAN you can do that but if you are talking about limit download speed someone else outside of the network you cannot. Start with networking concepts see how the ip address, submask, how packet is sent. etc then you need to know all the depth of how you can using java to assign the ports, ip and socket then you need to write the logic for ports and blocker to handle those limits. In short your question is not practical. it is like asking "how do I make a car that run fast". well I would say learn to make car first

Comment: @Kayaman yes u r right that is what i m looking to achieve.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @saki But you can't limit my download speed. You're not my ISP.

Comment: @Kayaman, I hope that saki really wanted to limit someone connected to their server, otherwise there goes my 5 minutes spent on that question

Comment: @sleblanc You can waste hours on some people here.

Comment: @Kayaman He could if he were the person running the server, limiting per-client bandwidth. It wasn't stated explicitly that he was trying to limit arbitrary peers.

Comment: @chrylis Nothing was stated explicitly in this question, except that he's new to Java. Based on that I'm assuming that he has no code whatsoever, much less any working server.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer in a general way, without referring specifically to Java.

A common technique to throttle a connection is to wait after having read from the open socket. Your code can do a bit of logic to count how fast it has been downloading. There are many ways of accomplishing this and what you intend to do with this will influence how you do it.

In Python-like pseudocode:

```
data_per_timeslot = 500 * 1000 # 500 KB/s
timeslot = 1000 * 1000 # 1 sec (in us)

with new_connection() as conn:
    download_complete = False
    chunk_size = data_per_sec

    ts = nil

    while not download_complete:
        ts = time()
        buffer = conn.read(chunk_size)
        diff = time() - ts

        # do something with data
        data.append(buffer) 

        # sleep if there is still time left in our timeslot,
        # to throttle the connection a bit
        if diff < timeslot: 
            usleep(timeslot - diff)
```

If you need throttling to remove excessive strain on a server, it makes sense to give a little boost to the user if the connection speed dipped during the last few seconds. Say I am downloading at 500 KB/s (throttled); I load a page in my browser and the download goes down at 250 KB/s for a few seconds; the client should be allowed to "catch up" by raising the download speed in bursts of a few hundreds of KB/s.

However, if you need throttling in the context of a video conference app or similar, it will not make sense to boost the transfer speed after it sagged since there is no data to "catch up" to; in realtime video, you drop missing frames instead.

Comment: @Saki, if you want to limit another person's bandwidth, you will have to pull strings at their ISP, and it is very likely highly illegal. However if someone is connected to your server and you want to throttle them, what I wrote applies (change `read` with `write`).